# PHP design pattern for logging

Tags: php, design-patterns

I have a class which logs a record into a file each time one of it's functions its called.

I would like to avoid including the logging code into each function. I don't believe it's a good coding practice.

```
class Foo {
   function foo1() {
       file_put_contents("log","Foo1 has been called");
       // do something
   }
   function foo2() {
       file_put_contents("log","Foo2 has been called");
       // do something
   }
   function foo3() {
       file_put_contents("log","Foo3 has been called";
       // do something
   }
}
```

I want to take out the file_put_contents() from each function but still write the log when a function is called!. Is there any design pattern to do that?

Comment: Traits! http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php

Comment: The PHP Framework Interopability Group recently formalised a standard design pattern for writing logging classes. You might be interested in having a look -- http://www.phpdeveloper.org/news/19037

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're looking for the [Observer pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern).

Here's a blog post with an example that is similar enough in concept for your concerns
http://labelmedia.co.uk/blog/posts/php-design-patterns-observer-pattern.html